# How to use variable in pgsql's \copy command?

Tags: postgresql, variables, copy

In my postgresql's shell,set variable's value as '2023-11-01':

```
\set date  '2023-11-01'
```

Call it :

```
\echo :'date'
'2023-11-01'
\echo :date
2023-11-01
```

Use it in select

```
select * from quote where date=:'date';
```

It output all records in quote when date is `2023-11-01`,i want to copy all the records into `/tmp/records.csv`:

```
\copy (select * from quote where date=:'date')  to '/tmp/result.csv' 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: COPY  ( select * from quote where date=: 'date' ) TO STDOU...
```

Same error for:

```
\copy (select * from quote where date=:date)  to '/tmp/result.csv'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> \copy ...  Unlike most other meta-commands, the entire remainder of the line is always taken to be the arguments of \copy, and neither variable interpolation nor backquote expansion are performed in the arguments.

> Tip

> Another way to obtain the same result as \copy ... to is to use the SQL COPY ... TO STDOUT command and terminate it with \g filename or \g |program. Unlike \copy, this method allows the command to span multiple lines; also, variable interpolation and backquote expansion can be used.

In your case:

```
copy (select * from quote where date=:'date')  to stdout \g '/tmp/result.csv'
```

Comment: why not \t ,t stand for terminate ,how g can stand for terminate?

Comment: Because it means terminate as finish the command with `\g`, where `\g` means: *Sends the current query buffer to the server for execution.*  FYI, `\t`  exists as: *Toggles the display of output column name headings and row count footer.*. It is spelled out further at the `psql` link I put in the answer.

Comment: Is there a word beginning with `g` means `terminate` in English?

Comment: Not that I know of.  From the description of `\g` at the `psql` link: *If the current query buffer is empty, the most recently sent query is re-executed instead. Except for that behavior, \g without any arguments is essentially equivalent to a semicolon.* So it offers a way to finish(terminate) the command and do something with the results. As to the `g`. I suspect that was on of the few alphabet characters left to use for a meta-command. I would highly recommend you read the information at the `psql` link.

Comment: I have persuaded myself to accept by imaging `g` as `goto`,from standard output ,go into   other output foramt--file.